# Insertar salto de linea en SQL SERVER desde PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

ejecuto una sentencia de SQL SERVER desde el PHP, y necesito que tengas salto de linea, ya que el sistema del SQL SERVER las requiere.

Codigo PHP:

```
$QueryTable = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE 
name='$NombreTabla' AND xtype='U') CREATE TABLE $NombreTabla ( $Columnas ) GO";
```

El SQL SERVER requiere que yo inserte saltos de linea una vez terminado el condicional, y una vez terminada la sentencia que crea la tabla.

Esto es lo que busco:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='$NombreTabla' 
AND xtype='U')
CREATE TABLE $NombreTabla ( $Columnas ) 
GO"
```

Cual seria la forma correcta de escribir mi codigo PHP? 
Desde ya muchas gracias, y perdon por la redaccion.

Comment: puedes probar con \n ya que lo que pasa es una cadena

Comment: Te agradezco mucho Juan Carlos, pero al pasar esa sentencia al SQL no la toma. No me funciono con backslash n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah **PHP** no le interesa como uses los string. Entonces podes intentar con lo siguiente:

1. Manual (ingresas espacios y saltos)

```
$QueryTable = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='$NombreTabla'                                                        
AND xtype='U')                                                                  
CREATE TABLE $NombreTabla ( $Columnas )                                           
GO";
```

No es practica pero podes aplicarla.

2. Cadenas y puntos

```
$QueryTable = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='$NombreTabla'".                                                        
"AND xtype='U')    ".                                                              
"CREATE TABLE $NombreTabla ( $Columnas ) ".                                          
"GO";
```

3. Usando los operadores de escape:

```
$QueryTable = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='$NombreTabla' AND xtype='U')\n CREATE TABLE $NombreTabla ( $Columnas )\n GO";
```

La 3 es la que utilizo yo, utiliza la que más gustes.

Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias SourceCode, el primer metodo no me resulto, el segundo no lo probe, y el tercero no me funciono tampoco. Opte por cambiar el modo de la consunlta, e instertale a la consulta un BEGIN y un END. 

De ese modo pude colocar todo en una misma linea. 

Voy a seguir intentando sobre tus aclaraciones. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Deberás, seguí intentado. Yo las eh utilizado y funcionan bien.